# Access data source of main program in user control

Tags: c#, .net, oop, datagridview, user-controls

I would like to write a program that uses several tabs, each showing a data grid. The data of all the grids is stored in a single data source. Each tab should look identical except for the number of colums/rows and the values of course.

So I am now trying to put the grid view into a user control and create a .dll. If a tab is added I put the user control into it - this works already. The grid works in virtual mode and if a new tab/grid is created it calls the event to load the data into the grid.

Now I have the problem that the grid and the LoadData event are in the user control while the data source is in my main program. So in the user control the data source is undefined. I thought that this would be ok because you do not run the user control alone and once it is used in the main program the data source should be available to the LoadData event. However, it does not seems to be possible to generate the .dll while the data source is unknown.

On the other hand I do not want to put the data source into the user control because then it is dublicated every time a new tab is created.

I hope you can give me a hint what is the best way to implement it.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what answer (how detailed) you expect, but I think this is a very good example to:

- reuse one control
- use MVVM architecture pattern

I would try to seperate class which would execute logic responsible for creating ViewModel. Control (grid in your purpose) would be always binded to this ViewModel, and this Control would be reuse in different Views. Depend on where it would be placed you can add some additional features if it is necessary (Decorator design pattern). If you expected more detailed (not conceptual) solution than sorry.

Comment: Yes, conceptual is ok, I did not expect any code or so. Just I would like to avoid data binding. This is to complicate to me, especially because the data is stored in a lua table and I am using LuaInterface to access it. So the data is not held in a usual c# data structure.

Comment: I have never heard about LuaInterface, so I can't help you, but wish you luck.